# How to extend Sump Pump discharge pipe from house

Tags: plumbing, foundation, sump-pump

My house's sump pump discharge pipe exit's the house a couple of feet high from the ground and runs straight down.  I don't want it dumping right next to the house (kid's sandbox is there now) so I was thinking of adding a 90 degree elbow and running it to a different spot away from the sandbox.

I'd rather not discharge the water right next to the foundation, but I also don't want to extend the pipe into the yard where the kids could trip over it (nor do I want to mow around it).  Any ideas on how to discharge away from the foundation without being a hazard?

Comment: Is there any possibility of tying into the water lines for your gutters? That is how my pump drains.

Comment: It might be possible.  How do you tie your pvc pipe into the metal downspout?

Comment: Here is a basic demonstration of the idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P43TbpEgC-o

Comment: Do you have storm drainage in your area? Some areas have municipal storm sewers, that they can connect downspouts and sump discharge to. If not, you could discharge the water through underground pipes to a ditch, dry well, or other drainage location.

Comment: For what it's worth, I set up my outlet at a corner of the house, with black flex tubing leafing off thru the plantings and along my fence to the discharge point, so it isn't running thru areas that need mowing or are trip hazards.

Answer (score 2):

When i installed a sump pump in my previous house, to add a sink into the basement, I had it pump up as high as it could, on about a 45 degree angle, then let it run down with the help of gravity to where i want it to discharge.

Answer (score 1):

Bury [black corrugated landacape drain](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Advanced-Drainage-Systems-6-in-x-10-ft-Corex-Drain-Pipe-Perforated-06010010/203298661?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7C&gclid=Cj0KEQiAtri0BRDLoaCF95e7o_sBEiQA_pgRQzGCniLGVzCfvFMHB11f-3LpEbXwx6fYtwlrvbZWW0IaAhKx8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) beneath your sump discharge.  Use solid drain to get some distance from your house.  Then use the perforated version surrounded by gravel to give the water somewhere to go.

I did this and also ran it past one of my downspouts, so that both of them are concealed below grade now.

Or you can daylight it if the land slopes down as you get away from your house, or discharge it into an underground pit of gravel, or a storm sewer, or rain barel or whathot....

If your climate includes times of year when its below freezing outside, its worth keeping the rigid PVC section of the discharge as short and close to the house as possible.  Better for the drain grate to ice over and get ice on the ground than for the pvc to freeze up internally, shatter, and burn out your pump.

Answer (score 0):

I brought mine out to a fitting onto which I've clamped a length of 2" flex hose; that goes under my rainbarrel platform and along the property line to about 20' from the house. The *right* answer would be to then run it into a drywell, but...

I suppose one could bury piping, but then you'd have to worry about freezing. My setup does have that risk but less so, I think.

It isn't uncommon for folks to install permanent catch pipes for their rain gutters, to route them away from the house. A sump pump might or might not be able to feed into that...